# Xamarin Image on Button is crashing

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have a Button where I want to add an image, but the app is crashing when the view gets loaded (view doesn't even show up, using Xamarin Live Player). If I create an extra image field the image shows up.

Here is the code:

```
<Image Grid.Row="3" Source="trash.png"></Image>
<Button Grid.Row="4" Image="trash.png" ></Button>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: If you directly deploy(&debug) to your device without using Live Player, do you receive an error/exception/... ?

Comment: @SushiHangoverthx, seems like to be a bug from the Xamarin Live Player..

Comment: You might want to post the details on the Visual Studio problem forum for the MSFT devs to see @ https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html?all

Comment: yeah I will do that as soon as I got time for it :D